# Мердж в главную ветку Git

Tags: git

Пусть есть такие ветки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли сделать мердж ветки 1 в main, а после этого мердж ветки 2, если изменения файлов в ветках 1 и 2 не пересекаются?

Comment: Да, если изменения не пересекаются, то, скорее всего, конфликтов не будет, значит можно будет слить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge можно выполнить даже если правки пересекаются. Разница будет только в наличии/отсутствии конфликтов, которые необходимо разрешить вручную.

В данной схеме при попытке выполнить первое слияние без явного указания `--no-ff` будет выполнена "перемотка", то есть ветка main поднимется по дереву до ветки 1 без создания коммита слияния.

Comment: Ещё .gitconfig может влиять на fast forward.